# Print a word document in javascript instead of downloading it

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing

I have a link which points to a .docx or PDF file. When a user clicks on the link, instead of downloading/showing it...I would like to popup a print window. I tried doing the following but I'm getting an error:

```
    var e = document.getElementById("download_1");
    e.print();
    return false;
```

Embed file:

```
 <embed src ="/files/test.doc" width="0" height="0" name="download_1"></embed>
```

I'm getting an error:

TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'e.print()')

Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/zip.

Comment: I don't think the browser's print function can cause an embedded document to print. Not to mention the fact that the browser's settings determine how a PDF or DOC is displayed, not your embed code.

Comment: What do I need to do with make this work in chrome? I don't care about IE, FF or safari.

Answer (score 0):

You can not tell the browser to print a specific document, since [*`window.print`*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.print) will only bring up the print dialog. ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.print))

JavaScript is not very useful for handling files, but you can use Flash. I googled it and I found [a link](http://www.actionscript.org/resources/articles/206/1/The-PrintJob-class/Page1.html) which it maybe works for you.